# Change templating to native html files in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing application using spring boot 1.3.2

I want to remove a Thymeleaf template engine from my web app. All my html files are in directory `resource/template/html` my SpringBoot configuration class contains bean:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("html/search/wellcomeScreen");
            registry.addViewController("/offers").setViewName("html/search/offersearch/searchScreen");
        }
    }
}
```

When I move my html files from `resource/template/html` to `resource/static/html` directory how do I create url to reffer to my html files to map file `/static/html/search/offersearch/search` to `/offers` ?